# Google Maps V3 and infobox in IE8

Tags: google-maps, infobox

I have an infobox working fine by click in all browsers except for IE8 and below, it shows the error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setContent' which I can't really understand as it clearly works in other browsers. The part of code in question:

```
function listenInfoWindows(marker, content) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      this.getMap().setCenter(this.getPosition());
      this.getMap().panBy(0,-80);
      infobox.setContent(content);
      infobox.open(map, this);
    }
  );
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where did `infobox` get created?

Comment: are there any elements inside the document with the ID infobox?

Comment: Yes - is this a problem? Will include my entire js file

Comment: I've just noticed that it has a problem with this line: infobox = new InfoBox (SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method. IE8 doesn't even load the markers in this case. I tried adding 'var', this makes it load the markers but the infobox doesn't work. Also it then doesn't work in other browsers!

Comment: AHA Dr. Molle I think you cracked it - I changed the ID in my HTML and it's working - thanks!